# Android apps interaction

Tags: android

I'm investigating if I can make an app that runs in background but is able to interact with others by "enriching" texts adding relevant information. For Instance, interact with an existent twitter app colouring words considered to be relevant. Thanks in advacen for any help

Answer (score 0):

No, you really cannot without the application(s) in question directly invoking or intentionally calling upon your application for the desired functionality.